# Determine constness using template functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I would like to determine if a type is const or not using a template function, e.g.:

```
template <typename TTYPE> bool IsConst(TTYPE) {return false;}

template <typename TTYPE> bool IsConst(const TTYPE) {return true;}
```

But this does not work, any alternative suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at `boost::type_traits`? Or RTTI?

Comment: How are you using your `IsConst` function templates?

Answer (score 11):

What you're looking for is [`std::is_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const). If the type you give it is const, `value` will be `true`. If not, `value` will be `false`.

Here's the example you can find on that page:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> //needed for is_const

int main() 
{
    std::cout << boolalpha; //display true/false, not 1/0
    std::cout << std::is_const<int>::value << '\n'; //int isn't const
    std::cout << std::is_const<const int>::value  << '\n'; //const int is const
}
```

Output:

```
false
true
```

Since you tried making your own, I would recommend you look through the possible implementation that is provided to get a feel of how these things work, in case you do need to make one in the future. It is a good learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct isConst
{
    static bool result;
};

template<typename T>
struct isConst<const T>
{
    static bool result;
};

template<typename T>
bool isConst<T>::result = false;

template<typename T>
bool isConst<const T>::result = true;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << isConst<int>::result << "\n";
    std::cout << isConst<const int>::result << "\n";
    std::cout << isConst<const char>::result << "\n";
    std::cout << isConst<char*>::result << "\n";
    std::cout << isConst<const float>::result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I solve your problem with template specializations. When `T` is `const` the specialized (second) version is called automatically. If you compile and run this code you will get:

```
false
true
true
false
true
```

Your version doesn't work, because you redefine the `IsConst` function (it is forbidden and causes compiler error)

**Note:** I changed the `result()` function with a static variable. It also works and it's faster.

Comment: This disadvantage of this method is that `result` is a function, not a compile-time constant.

Comment: Indeed. That's why the result is usually just a data member of the class in metaprogramming. Also, `class C { public: ... };` can simply be replaced with `struct C { ... };` in C++.

Comment: I think his function rather didn't work because it was a function and he probably used it in a context where he needed a compile time constant. Thus marking his function `constexpr` should have made it work. I don't think overloading is a problem here. But chris' answer is the right way to go anyway (or yours for a pre-11 implementation). By the way, why the trivial default constructors?